# packagist laravel package -composer Could not find package

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php, package, packagist

I have created package using Laravel.

- The composer.json file for my package will look like this

  ```
  {
  "name": "lakshmajim/testview",
  "description": "hi",
  "keywords": [
      "package"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/lakshmajim/testview",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
      {
          "name": "lakshmajim",
          "email": "lakshmaji9@gmail.com"
      }
  ],
  "require": {
              "php": ">=5.3.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
          "lakshmajim\\testview\\": "src/"
      }
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev"
  ```

  }
- then I have pulled to [github](https://github.com/lakshmajim/testview)
- then I have linked it to [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/lakshmajim/testview)
- when I am running this `composer require lakshmajim/testview`
  it is showing following error message

  **[InvalidArgumentException]

    Could not find package lakshmajim/testview at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-s

    tability**

**QUESTION**:
Why I am getting that error message ,when I'm trying to install using composer?
How can I successfully run composer require lakshmajim/testview

Answer (score 13, accepted):

it's a release issue 
you must run

```
composer require lakshmajim/testview dev-master
```

you don't have a release yet.

Comment: How can I made it to release??

Comment: i'ts simple, go ahead to your repository on github and make release.

Comment: check this out [How To make a release](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/)

Comment: **Thank you Houssain**

Comment: **Upvote for you @HoussainAmrani**. Thank you very much !! Spent 4 hours to understand I had to do a release !!!